# rpm provides shared object that is also required by a provided executable

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

Preface: Auto dependencies (AutoReqProv) is ON

As the title says, we have a shared object that is provided by the RPM package we have built, so it is placed in the %files section of the spec file. However, we have executable files in the %files section as well, that are dependent on this .so. So, with auto dependencies on, it is trying to resolve this issue during install of this package. Obviously, this .so has not been installed yet on the target system because it is apart of the package being installed. So, it throws an install error.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Auto dependencies being on is a requirement for this, so removing it is a last ditch effort.

**Edit: Here is the %files section of my spec file. The .so in question is located in /usr/local/%{name}

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/usr/local/%{name}
/usr/bin/*
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
/etc/opt/aubit4gl2
/usr/lib/*
%attr(0755, -, -) /usr/local/bin/c4glpg
%attr(0755, -, -) /usr/local/bin/c4glpg2
```

The error is this:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
libaubit4gl.so is needed by aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i686
```

Edit 2: Here is the install section of the rpmbuild command output

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILD/aubit4gl2-10.0.4/aubit4gl2'
+ cp -a aubit4gl2/atomix4pg/sqldist /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/local/aubit4gl2/atomix4pg
+ cp -a aubit4gl2/etc/aubitrc /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/etc/opt/aubit4gl2
+ sed -i 's/^AUBITETC=.*/AUBITETC=\/etc\/opt\/aubit4gl2/g' /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/etc/opt/aubit4gl2/aubitrc
+ sed -i 's/^AUBITDIR=.*/AUBITDIR=\/usr\/local\/aubit4gl2/g' /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/etc/opt/aubit4gl2/aubitrc
+ sed -i 's/^AUBITDIR_SRC=.*/AUBITDIR_SRC=\/usr\/local\/aubit4gl2/g' /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/etc/opt/aubit4gl2/aubitrc
+ echo '# NOBLE: Make aubit utils only create 32-bit output'
+ echo CFLAGS=-m32
+ ln -s /usr/local/aubit4gl2/lib/libaubit4gl.so /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/lib/libaubit4gl.so
+ ln -s /usr/local/aubit4gl2/atomix4pg/bin/c4glpg /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/local/bin/c4glpg
+ ln -s /usr/local/aubit4gl2/atomix4pg/bin/c4glpg2 /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/local/bin/c4glpg2
+ ln -s /usr/local/aubit4gl2/bin/amake /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/bin/amake
+ ln -s /usr/local/aubit4gl2/bin/aubit /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/bin/aubit
+ ln -s /usr/local/aubit4gl2/bin/aubit-config /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/bin/aubit-config
Processing files: aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i686
warning: Explicit %attr() mode not applicaple to symlink: /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/local/bin/c4glpg
warning: Explicit %attr() mode not applicaple to symlink: /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386/usr/local/bin/c4glpg2
Provides: libA4GL_HTML.so libA4GL_file.so libA4GL_memcache.so libA4GL_pcre.so libA4GL_pick.so libA4GL_roman.so libA4GL_string.so libDATA_module.so libDATA_module_definition.so libDATA_report.so libDATA_struct_form.so libEXREPORT_NOPDF.so libFORM_GENERIC.so libFORM_NOFORM.so libFORM_XDR.so libHELP_std.so libLEX_C.so libLEX_CS.so libLEX_EC.so libLEX_PERL.so libLEX_WRITE.so libLOGREPPROC_CSV.so libLOGREPPROC_HTML.so libLOGREPPROC_TXT.so libLOGREP_CSV.so libLOGREP_HTML.so libLOGREP_TXT.so libMSG_NATIVE.so libPACKER_FORMXML.so libPACKER_GZPACKED.so libPACKER_MEMPACKED.so libPACKER_PACKED.so libPACKER_PERL.so libPACKER_XDR.so libPACKER_XML.so libRPC_NORPC.so libRPC_XDR.so libSQLPARSE_INFORMIX.so libSQLPARSE_NONE.so libSQL_FILESCHEMA.so libSQL_nosql.so libSQL_unixodbc.so libUI_CONSOLE.so libUI_HL_GTK.so libUI_HL_TUI.so libUI_HL_TUIN.so libUI_TUI.so libUI_TUI_wide.so libUI_XML.so libXDRPACKER_module.so libXDRPACKER_module_definition.so libXDRPACKER_report.so libXDRPACKER_struct_form.so libaubit4gl-1.2_39.so libbarcode.so libchannel.so liberrhook_sample.so aubit4gl2 = 10.0.4-2 aubit4gl2(x86-32) = 10.0.4-2 perl(report) perl(using)
Requires(interp): /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh
Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
Requires(pre): /bin/sh
Requires(post): /bin/sh
Requires(postun): /bin/sh
Requires: /bin/sh /usr/bin/perl libatk-1.0.so.0 libaubit4gl-1.2_39.so libaubit4gl.so libc.so.6 libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.12) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) libcairo.so.2 libcurl.so.4 libdl.so.2 libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) libfontconfig.so.1 libform.so.5 libformw.so.5 libfreetype.so.6 libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 libgio-2.0.so.0 libglib-2.0.so.0 libgobject-2.0.so.0 libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 libm.so.6 libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) libncurses.so.5 libncursesw.so.5 libodbc.so.2 libpanel.so.5 libpanelw.so.5 libpango-1.0.so.0 libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 libpcre.so.1 libpthread.so.0 libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) libtinfo.so.5 libz.so.1 perl(DBI) perl(Date::Calc) perl(strict) perl(using) rtld(GNU_HASH)
Processing files: libaubit4gl-1.2_39-2.i686
Provides: libaubit4gl = 1.2_39-2 libaubit4gl(x86-32) = 1.2_39-2 libaubit4gl-1.2_39.so
Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
Requires: libc.so.6 libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) libcurl.so.4 libdl.so.2 libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) libm.so.6 libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) libz.so.1 rtld(GNU_HASH)
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386
Wrote: /home/bhand/rpmbuild/SRPMS/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.src.rpm
Wrote: /home/bhand/rpmbuild/RPMS/i686/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i686.rpm
Wrote: /home/bhand/rpmbuild/RPMS/i686/libaubit4gl-1.2_39-2.i686.rpm
Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /home/bhand/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.wtiBPg
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd aubit4gl2-10.0.4
+ rm -rf /home/bhand/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i386
+ exit 0
cp ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/i686/aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.i686.rpm aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.centos.7.postgres.i686.rpm
cp ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/i686/libaubit4gl-1.2_39-2.i686.rpm libaubit4gl-1.2_39-2.i686.rpm
cp RELEASENOTES aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.centos.7.postgres.i686.RELEASENOTES
```

Edit 3: The output of rpm -qlvp aubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.centos.7.postgres.i686.rpm

```
rpm -qlvp nscaubit4gl2-10.0.4-2.centos.7.postgres.i686.rpm | grep libaubit4gl
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root    root                       42 Oct 11 14:06 /usr/lib/libaubit4gl.so -> /usr/local/nscaubit4gl2/lib/libaubit4gl.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root    root                  2439297 Oct 11 14:06 /usr/local/nscaubit4gl2/lib/libaubit4gl-1.2_39.so
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root    root                       21 Oct 11 14:06 /usr/local/nscaubit4gl2/lib/libaubit4gl.so -> libaubit4gl-1.2_39.so
```

Comment: a library and a binary in the same package should not throw errors. There must be something else going one. Can you give use the %files section as well as the error you get when trying to install that rpm ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with what you've asked for. I don't completely understand how it should be okay, though. If that .so is provided by our RPM (i.e: not installed on the target system), and one of the executables requires it, I would expect to have an error. Or is RPM supposed to be smart enough to handle that?

Comment: rpm is supposed to be smart enough. However; /usr/local/ is NOT in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH by default; so I don't think that's a good idea. I would suggest you to install your lib in /usr/lib. Also to be sure that your .so is packaged well, run `rpm -qlp <your produced rpm file>` and check if your .so is in the list.

Comment: Well, the library starts off in /usr/local/%{name}. It is placed into /usr/lib during the install process. But, with auto deps on, it can't even get to the install because of this failing dependency on a library that isn't installed yet. I've got a little less than a year of experience with linux/rpm, so this is just a beginner's theory. I could be totally wrong, but this error makes sense to me. Just don't know how to work around it right now. Oh, and querying for the library in the package is successful.

Comment: I've been packaging rpms for three years now. I can guarantee you I never had an issue packaging library and executable together! The problem must lie somewhere else... When you query your package, the so shows up in /usr/lib?

Comment: Yes, it does show up in /usr/lib.

Comment: Really strange...  Could you print the complete output of the rpmbuild command? I'll take a look on Monday...

Comment: The complete output is literally thousands of lines long (it's pretty big software). What exactly are you wanting to see? I'll try to pick out the relevant part from the output for you.

Comment: The part starting with the install section until the end if that is possible.

Comment: I've added the install section of the rpmbuild. Note that what I've pasted has the "libaubit4gl" subpackage included. This was an attempt at fixing the issue, and was not present when I initially asked the question. The dependency error remains the same, so it shouldn't effect the nature of the original question. Please let me know if you have any questions, and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I guess I can see the problem now: if I understand the log well, you are only packaging the symbolic link to /usr/local... But not the actual .so. it might very well be that the .so is present in that location, but that doesn't mean rpm knows that. Rpm knows only about the files installed by rpms. Not files present on the file system.

Comment: Well, I believe I'm making the sym link in the %install section, but the entire /usr/local... is included in the package per the %files list. So, the library should be, too, yeah? I actually even tried creating a subpackage containing only the .so and installing that before the primary package. Still complains about dependency issues. RPM just can't seem to find this library...

Comment: Could you add the output of the 'rpm -qlvp < your rpm> then? I don't see the installation of /usr/local in the install section you just showed.

Comment: Ok. I've provided the output.

Comment: I'm sorry I fail to see why this doesn't work. Everything is very complicated in your spec file. I just install library in /usr/lib and I never had any problem... One more case I can imagine: is there a line "Requires:libaubit4gl.so" in the spec file?

Comment: No, but I've tried adding it just to see what would happen. It still does not work. Thanks for trying though, I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the library has the executable bits on.

Comment: This worked nicely for me, where my library was missing from the provides list.  I did have to set the permissions during the %install phase, and not by using %attr in the %files section.  RPM version 4.11.3

Answer (score 1):

I added "Provides: libaubit4gl.so" to my spec file and it works now. For some reason, RPM was saying that the aubit4gl package was not providing this .so.

I'm still not 100% on why that is. But, this is what solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If any file in the package's %files list is a shared library, the library's SONAME is automatically added to the list of capabilities the package provides.

In my case SONAME for the shared library is empty. After setting SONAME for shared library(as below using -Wl option in gcc) packging the modified shared library worked fine (automatically resolved capabilities).

To test whether SONAME is set properly you can use command `objdump -p libaubit4gl.so | grep SONAME`

SONAME is assigned/embedded into shared library during linking as below

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libaubit4gl.so -o libaubit4gl.so foo.o bar.o baz.o -lc
```

SONAME can be different from file name libaubit4gl.so.
(Note: This is not as per standard but suggesting this to get rid of your error. However if you want to name shared library as per standards see [versioning a shared library](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/build_a_shared_library_using_gcc.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could have your spec file create two .rpm files: a `libaubit4gl` one and a `aubit4gl` one. The first provides this library and the other one requires it.

At least, this seems kind of good practice to me, at least if the library can be used w/o the binary.

Comment: This is sort of what I was thinking. Your wording got me in the right direction for a good Google search though. I'm currently looking at rpm subpackages, which I did not know was a thing until 30 minutes ago. Will update if it works.

Comment: Update on this: Installing the library from a separate package before installing aubit4gl still gives me a dependency issue. Really have no idea why.

Comment: @pid_1 Here you could check what a) the library package provides and b) what the "main" package requires.

Comment: They do what you'd expect, which is why this whole thing is so bizarre. The library package provides the .so, and the aubit4gl "main" package requires it. This is confirmed in the rpmbuild output. Installing the library package puts the .so in /usr/lib, which is a sym link to the actual library. The "main" package still complains of failing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I was setting the executable bits on the created library with %file %attr, but it turned out that I wasn't setting the executable bits in my %install phase.

Setting the shared library file to 755 during %install AND %files fixed the problem.

I'm guessing that rpmbuild looks at the files in the BUILD directory for its analysis, so they have to be correct there, not just after the "rpm -i" installation.